# Using port.onDisconnect to determine when a Chrome extension is uninstalled / disabled

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I know that Chrome extension API doesn't have an official way of determining when a user uninstalls your extension (which is a shame).

I am using the port.onDisconnect listener from my content-script page after connecting to the background page to determine when a user uninstalls/disables my extension. According to the docs port.onDisconnect should only fire when the extension doesn't exist anymore (or when port.disconnect is explicitly called from the background page) which should cover the disable / uninstall scenario.

This actually works perfectly on my machine. Whenever I uninstall or disable my extension, port.onDisconnect is fired as it's supposed to (once per open tab). The problem is I am seeing this event fired from MANY of my actual users. I am 99% sure that not this many users are disabling / uninstalling my extension (I see them perform other tasks later on with my extension and my extension installation numbers doesn't show that many uninstalls).

This leads me to believe that there is some other condition that fires port.onDisconnect other than disabling/uninstalling an extension. I cannot reproduce this at all on my machine. On my machine, port.onDisconnect is only fired when I disable/uninstall the extension and I don't call port.disconnect explicitly from my background page anywhere.

So my question is: what could be the condition(s) that fires port.onDisconnect other than the user disabling/uninstalling an extension? I thought a version upgrade of the extension could cause this behavior but I tested it on my machine and I don't think that's it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can I just confirm that you're adding the listener to the [Port](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#type-Port) object returned by [chrome.extension.connect](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-connect) and **not** [chrome.tabs.connect](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-connect).

Comment: That is correct Alasdair. Here's my code in my content script: `code` $(document).ready(function() {
 port = chrome.extension.connect(); port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() { // user disable/uninstall });
}); `code`

Comment: Won't port.onDisconnect get called when a tab closes?

Answer (score 0):

If you're content script is adding a listener every time it is injected, the listeners of each open page/tab that this script has been run in will be executed.

A single user could uninstall/disable your extension but may have had 10 affected pages/tabs open, so it might appear that 10 users did this.

I'm not sure what the best way around this is, if any, since what you're trying to achieve isn't really supported.

Comment: Alasdair, sorry maybe I wasn't clear on this. Yes, I know that when a user uninstalls my extension and he has 10 tabs open port.onDisconnect will fire 10 times. I am already accounting for this on my server side. My issue isn't that I am getting this event fired many times from one user (that is expected). The issue is this event is getting fired for too many USERS. I really don't think this many people are disabling/uninstalling my extension but I can't figure out what would cause this event to be fired for this many users except disabling/uninstalling.